# Getting Invalid Syntax error in Register section when inserting into database - cs50 Finance (pset8)

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error, cs50

I can't get past the Register section of CS50 Finance without an Internal Service Error. The issue arises from an Invalid Syntax error when I go to insert a new user's username and password hash into the users table.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    # return error messages if any field is left blank
    if not request.form.get("username"):
        return apology("Must provide username", 403)
    elif not request.form.get("password"):
        return apology("Must provide password", 403)
    elif not request.form.get("confirmation"):
        return apology("Must provide password confirmation", 403)

    # make sure the username does not already exist and that the passwords match
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
                      username = request.form.get("username"))
    if len(rows) > 0:
        return apology("Sorry, this username already taken.", 403)
    # make sure password and password confirmation match
    elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirmation"):
        return apology("Passwords do not match.", 403)

    # declare username and hash variables to clean up SQL code
    username = request.form.get("username")
    hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))

    # insert new user's username and password hash into users table
    db.execute=("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)",
                 username=username,
                 hash=hash)

else:
    return render_template("register.html")
```

The syntax error is in the db.execute block:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/pset8/finance/application.py", line 143
    username=username,
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried changing the name of username, putting the variable assignment in the actual db.execute block instead of above, and even different SQL code, but nothing has worked.

I believe this is the only place I have an error in my code because when I comment out the db.execute block, the Finance site loads fine and I get the correct error messages.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You mean `db.execute("INSERT INTO` (note the lack of `=`). With the `=`, you're trying to use keyword args in a tuple literal, which isn't valid.

Comment: I can't say thank you enough!! Appreciate it!